# Python / Heroku - Twitter bot reposting duplicate image, time.sleep() not working properly

Tags: python, heroku, twitter

I have a twitter bot that downloads a .jpg image from the internet and posts it to twitter. This has been set on a loop every 6 hours

```
while True:
    top_image = import_posts()
    tweet(top_image)
    time.sleep(60*60*6)
    os.remove(top_image)
```

The first problem is my bot reposted the same image. This didn't happen when I run the app from my machine, but occurs when running through Heroku. When I download a .jpg, I put the URL it downloads from into urls.txt, and whenever import_posts() runs it reads the textfile and skips any previously used images. Is this because the urls.txt doesn't update on the Heroku side? It also may be related to the second issue...

The second issue is the Heroku app seemed to go to sleep after the first tweet was posted, then about an hour later it woke up and immediately posted the same image twice, even though it should wait for 6 hours

```
time.sleep(60*60*6)
```

This might be related to Dynos and how they go to sleep after a while of no web traffic. I can't remember for sure but I tested hosting on Heroku but posting an image every 1 minute, and if I remember correctly the second image was different from the first, meaning the Heroku Dyno timeout might be wiping the urls.txt file?

full code below:

```
import praw
import wget
import time
import os
import tweepy
import os
from os import environ

def import_posts():

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='hidden', client_secret='hidden', user_agent='hidden')

hot_posts = reddit.subreddit('Test').top("day", limit=10)
top_image = ""

for post in hot_posts:

    url_used = False
    textfile = open("urls.txt", "r")
    if post.url in textfile.read():
        url_used = True
        print(post.url + " has already been used")
    textfile.close()

    if url_used == False:           #only processes image if it hasn't been used
        image_filename = wget.download(post.url)
        print("Downloaded " + image_filename)
        top_image = image_filename
        appendfile = open("urls.txt", "a")
        appendfile.write(post.url+"\n")
        appendfile.close()
        break            #breaks out of loop whenever an image is processed
return top_image

def tweet(filename):
    consumer_key = environ['CONSUMER_KEY']
    consumer_secret = environ['CONSUMER_SECRET']
    access_token = environ['ACCESS_KEY']
    access_secret = environ['ACCESS_SECRET']

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    try:
        api.update_with_media(top_image)
        print("Tweeting " +filename)
    except:
        print("Error sending tweet")

def file_len(fname):                      #clears log after 300 posts
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    if i >= 300:
        file = open(fname, "w")
        file.truncate(0)
        file.close()
        print(fname + " has been cleared")
    i += 1
    print("There are " + str(i) +" URL entries in " + fname)
    return i

while True:
    top_image = import_hmmm_posts()
    tweet(top_image)
    file_len("urls.txt") 
    time.sleep(60*60*6)
    try:           #removes image from repository
        os.remove(top_image)
    except:
        print("Couldn't remove " + top_image)
```

Comment: only `web` dynos sleep. You aren't binding to a `port` so the 15 minutes sleep timeout is irrelevant to you. Dynos however reset once a day which is the problem. Upon the restart of your program you will tweet a previously sent picture again.

Comment: I am using a web dyno, it wouldn't work if I just used a worker.

app = Flask(__name__)
app.run(host= '0.0.0.0', port=environ.get('PORT'))

Comment: Your code doesn't mention `flask` anywhere. Where is this coming from? And why do you need a Flask app?

Comment: For Heroku you need a file called Procfile where you determine workers/web dynos. I have a web dyno which calls server.py, which imports flask and starts app.run(host= '0.0.0.0', port=environ.get('PORT'))

To be honest I only did the code for the twitter bot, I've been trying to follow a guide to get it running on Heroku which is where I've copied the Procfile / server.py stuff from.